# Optional match for beginning of line

Tags: python, regex, hashtag

I am trying to create a regular expression in Python that matches #hashtags. My definition on a hashtag is:

- It is a work that starts with a `#`
- It can contain all characters except `[ ,\.]`
- It can be anywhere in the text

So in this text

```
#This string cont#ains #four, and #only four #hashtags.
```

The hashes here are `This`, `four`, `only` and `hashtags`.

The problem I have is the optional check for the beginning of line.

- `[ \.,]+` won't do it since it won't match the optional beginning.
- `[ \.,]?` won't do it since it matches too much.

Example with +

```
In []: re.findall('[ \.,]+#([^ \.,]+)', '#This string cont#ains #four, and #only four #hashtags.')
Out[]: ['four', 'only', 'hashtags']
```

Example with ?

```
In []: re.findall('[ \.,]?#([^ \.,]+)', '#This string cont#ains #four, and #only four #hashtags.')
Out[]: ['This', 'ains', 'four', 'only', 'hashtags']
```

How can optional match the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\B#([^,\W]+)', '#This string cont#ains #four, and #only four #hashtags.')
['This', 'four', 'only', 'hashtags']
```

- **`\B`**: Matches the empty string, but only when it is not at the beginning or end of a word. This means that `r'py\B'` matches `'python'`, `'py3'`, `'py2'`, but not `'py'`, `'py.'`, or `'py!'`. `\B` is just the opposite of `\b`, so is also subject to the settings of `LOCALE` and `UNICODE`.
- **`\W`**: When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With LOCALE, it will match any character not in the set `[0-9_]`, and not defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match anything other than `[0-9_]` plus characters classied as not alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct response! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Before your regex you can just tell what you don't want.

```
(?<!\w)(#[^ \.,]+)
```

With negative lookbehind you can do that

Comment: This doesn't match the "#This" at the start of the string.